# How to calculate the generator matrix,parity check matrix and the maximum likelihood decoding

Tags: matrices, coding-theory, binary, maximum-likelihood, symmetric-matrices

An unknown encoding device for a binary linear block code has 4 bits of input-data pins and 8 bits of output data pins. If we send the messages

$$u_1=(1 1 0 0),\, u_2=(1010),\, u_3=(1001),\, u_4=(0001).$$

to the input, we can observe the following corresponding output vectors

$$x_1=(10101010),\, x_2=(11001100),\, x_3=(11110000),\, x_4=(00001111).$$

(1) Find the generator matrix $\mathbf G $,and parity check matrix $\mathbf H$.

(2)  Decode the following received vectors on a binary symmetric channel (with a 
     crossover probability $ < 1/2$) by using syndrome decoding:

$$_1 = (01101011),\,_2 = (00010110).$$

(3) Decode again using the maximum-likelihood decoding.

For the question (1),my formula is as below

$\mathbf C=\mathbf M \mathbf G$,so 
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf C & = \mathbf M \mathbf G \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} 
 & =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 4 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\times \mathbf G\\
\mathbf M^{-1} \times \mathbf C& =\mathbf G \\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix} &= \mathbf G 
\end{align}$$

I am not very sure about it,because i know $\mathbf G = [\mathbf F | \mathbf I]$,$\mathbf F$ is coefficient matrix and $\mathbf I$ is identity matrix,and $\mathbf H = [\mathbf I | \mathbf F^T]$. However, i can't let the second half of $\mathbf G$ become $\mathbf I$,so i wonder that is my calculation and thinking right?

About the (2) and (3),i have know idea how to calculate it,can anyone teach me?

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1196428/296687 might be helpful for the syndrome decoding.

Comment: @user160919 The OP does not seem to understand very much about binary codes or arithmetic operations in the binary field (as evidenced by his so-called solution to part (1) and the additional questions asked by him with regard to our respective answers) and so the reference you provide for syndrome decoding is not going to be very useful to him, or at least not at this time.

Comment: @DilipSarwate finally,i understand what are you explaining about,i will post a specific calculation processing later

Comment: @user160919  So the syndrome decoding is ,in fact, received vectors $\times H^T$?if the answer is 0 vector,the received signal itself is actually a codeword?

Comment: Yes, if $xH^T$ is the zero vector, then $x$ is a codeword. Do you see why?

Comment: @user160919  well,no!is it because $0$ means that no changed in this kind of code,so when the output is all $0$,it means that the generator matrix can't change something the input ,so the input is actually a codeword? i don't know the correct answer,this is just my guess

Comment: @ShineSun: I don't quite understand what you mean. But you only have to look at the definition of the parity check matrix. So, how is $H$ defined?

Comment: @user160919 $H=[I|F^T]$.

Comment: @ShineSun: Usually, the parity check matrix is defined as follows: The vector $x$ is a codeword in the code $C$ if and only if $xH^T=0$. If the generator matrix $G$ is in standard form, then you can use $H=[I|F^T]$. You should check out the wikipedia entry about the parity check matrix.

Comment: if all of them are 0,it means the 0th bit have to switch,so in fact,we don't need to switch any bit.But what if  this happening?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889846/what-if-there-is-no-enough-bit-to-change-syndrome-decoding ?strange!

Answer (score 1):

**Question (1):**

If $C$ is a code in $\mathbb{Z}_2^8$, then the generator matrix $G\in\mathbb{Z}_2^{4\times 8}$ is defined by
$$C=\{aG\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}_2^4\}.$$
To find the generator matrix, you take the standard basis $e_1,\dots,e_4$ of the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_2^4$, express the input vectors $u_1,\dots,u_4$ using this basis and compute the rows of $G$. Here, we have
\begin{align}
u_1&=e_1+e_2,\\
u_2&=e_1+e_3,\\
u_3&=e_1+e_4,\\
u_4&=e_4.
\end{align}
Since $u_4G=x_4$ and $u_4=e_4=(0,0,0,1)$, we immediately get the fourth row of $G$, which is $x_4$. Thus, we have $e_4G=x_4$ and since $x_3=u_3G=e_1G+e_4G=e_1G+x_4$, we then obtain $e_1G=x_3+x_4$, i.e., we also have the first row of $G$. Analogously, we get the second and third row of $G$. In summary, we have
$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The echelon form of $G$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
If the generator matrix has the form $[I_4\mid P]$, where $P$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix in this case, then we say that $G$ is in *standard form*. If you have this form, then you can get the parity check matrix $H$ with $H=[-P^T|I_4]$. But not all generator matrices are in standard form as you can see in this example. Therefore, we use a little trick and swap columns in the echelon form of $G$ to obtain $\widetilde{G}$, which is in standard form. Thus, we swap the third and fourth column to get
$$\widetilde{G}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&0&1&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix},$$
which has the desired form $[I_4|P]$. Hence, we obtain the corresponding parity check matrix $\widetilde{H}$ with
$$\widetilde{H}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&1&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
But this is not yet the parity check matrix we are looking for. Since we swapped the fourth and fifth column to obtain $\widetilde{G}$, we have to swap these columns in $\widetilde{H}$ to get $H$. Thus, we have
$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&0&1&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: What is your $\mathbf P$ matrix?

Comment: You said that  $G=[I_4|P]$,but you use$ \widetilde G =[I_4|P]$ after that.And it seems that $G$ is not equivalent to $ \widetilde G$,why can you just change two column to build $[I_4|P]$,it should not legal in calculate the echelon form

Comment: I edited my post a little bit and added some explanations why we can swap the columns.

Comment: i can't use the echelon form to let G become this ,can you write for more detail about it?$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The echelon form of $G$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Do you mean that you can't compute the echelon form of $G$?

Comment: i can't use the echelon form to let G become this ,can you write for more detail about it?$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The echelon form of $G$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$mine will become like this:$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&-1&0&-1&-1&-2\\
0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: You are working with binary codes, which means that you are working over the field $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$. So, what is $-1$ and $-2$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: so there can't be $-1$ and $-2$ in here,i have to use XOR,not the plus?

Comment: There is an addition for this field, which corresponds to the logical XOR operation. You can read about this in the following wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2). There, you can also find what -1 and -2 are in $\mathbb{F}_2$. If you want to work with linear codes, you should know the arithmetic in finite fields.

Comment: thx,ur right,i should use the XOR ,not the plus