# What if there is no enough bit to change (syndrome decoding)?

Tags: coding-theory

$y_1=(00010110)$,and the parity check matrix $\mathbf H$ is

$\mathbf H= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) $,and according to this question:[Use a parity check matrix for Ham(4,2) and syndrome decoding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196381/use-a-parity-check-matrix-for-ham4-2-and-syndrome-decoding/1196428#1196428) .The syndrome decoding is the $y_1H^T$,and the Nth bit have to  switch ,$1 \to 0$ or $0 \to 1$.

However,my result of  $y_1H^T$ is $1110$,that is,the $14th$ bit in the $y_1$ have to  switch ,but i have only $8$ bits in here,what do i do?or where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the first bit of $y_1$ since this column is the transpose of $1110$.  So $10010110$ is a code word.

Note that in this example, in contrast to the other problem you reference, the columns do not form the binary representations of $1,2,3,...$

Comment: I am confused now,so my calculation of $y_1H^T$ is $1110$,but according to the answer in the previous question,the $1110_2$ should be $14_{10}$,why should i switch the first bit?how did it be calculated? i mean,i don't understand this change the first bit of y1 since this column is the transpose of 1110

Comment: the columns do not form the binary representations of 1,2,3,...?but in the previous question,does't the author calculate the $y_1H^T$,and just switch the bit according to the $y_1H^T?$

Comment: You need to find the fewest number of columns of $H$ that add to the transpose of the syndrome, and then change the corresponding bits of $y$.

Comment: Do you mean $y_1[0001]$?

Comment: i still don't understand,could you please write the math formula to let me understand?

Comment: Changing a bit in the received word corresponds to changing the syndrome by the  (transpose of the) corresponding column of $H$.  So if the syndrome  matches a column of $H$ you just change the bit in the received word corresponding to that column of $H$.